# How to add one row from two drop down list to table and remove when select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two drop down list
first for projects
second for employees
I need when select value from first drop down list(projects) then select value from second drop down list (employee)
add new row of selected value from both two drop down list to table as following
suppose i select 
one  adil 
value selected removed from two drop down list both and inserted in table
and when make remove from table added to drop down list
my code as following

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        Project : <select id="myproject">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
        </select><br />
        Employees : <select id="myemployee">
            <option value="1">ahmed</option>
            <option value="2">mohamed</option>
            <option value="3">saiad</option>
            <option value="4">adil</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <table id="tb">
        <tr><td>ProjectName</td><td>EmployeeName</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

How i do that by jquery

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since you want to perform the insertion right after selecting the project and employee, to make sure the `change` event occurs, let's add a dummy option in your two `select`s first:

```
<div> 
    Project : <select id="myproject">
        <option value="">---select---</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        <option value="4">four</option>
    </select><br />
    Employees : <select id="myemployee">
        <option value="">---select---</option>
        <option value="1">ahmed</option>
        <option value="2">mohamed</option>
        <option value="3">saiad</option>
        <option value="4">adil</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

If you want to remove the row from table, maybe need another `<td>` to put the actions, so change the table to:

```
<table id="tb">
    <tr><td>ProjectName</td><td>EmployeeName</td><td>Action</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then create a JS function to do the insertion:

```
function removeAndAdd() {
    var project = $('#myproject option:selected').detach();
    var employee = $('#myemployee option:selected').detach();
    var newproject = '<td class="td-project" data-value="' + project.val() + '">' + project.text() + '</td>';
    var newemployee = '<td class="td-employee" data-value="' + employee.val() + '">' + employee.text() + '</td><td><button class="btn-remove">Remove</button></td>';
    $('#tb').append('<tr>' + newproject + newemployee + '</tr>');
}
```

this function will fetch the selected value from your dropdown lists and create a new row in the table. Next, bind the function to the `change` event of your `select`s:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    if (($('#myproject').val()) && ($('#myemployee').val())) {
        removeAndAdd();
    }
});
```

Finally, when the remove button is click, find the project and employee from the same row, insert them back to the dropdowns, and remove the row from the table:

```
$('#tb').on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var project = row.find('.td-project');
    var employee = row.find('.td-employee');
    $('#myproject').append('<option value="' + project.attr('data-value') + '">' + project.text() +'</option>');
    $('#myemployee').append('<option value="' + employee.attr('data-value') + '">' + employee.text() +'</option>');
    row.remove();
});
```

The full demo can be found [Here](https://jsbin.com/leqomowogu/edit?html,js,output)